# How to justify subfig subfloats?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, subfloats

I have three subfloats and I want them to be aligned over the full `\textwidth`, no matter what the sizes are (smaller than a third of the page of course).

I have the following setup:

```
\begin{figure} %
    \centering
    \subfloat[subcaption 1]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image1}} %
    %
    \subfloat[subcaption 2]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image2}} %
    %
    \subfloat[subcaption 3]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image3}} %

    \caption{%
    \label{fig:trans_actions} %
    Some caption text here. This is the full textwidth.}
\end{figure}
```

How do I get the images justified over the full width of the text?

Comment: While code snippets are useful for explaining things, t is _always_ best to compose a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Ok sure, I'll do that next time. I am always afraid that I'm making my examples too large and people can't read what the actual problem is anymore.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add `\hfill` to spread out the figures, which adds a rubber length that is allowed to stretch and shrink horizontally as needed.

The `[showframe]` option for the `geometry` pacakge was used to show the placement of the figures and the margins.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove demo option in real document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[subcaption 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image1}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[subcaption 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image2}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[subcaption 3]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image3}}
    \caption{\label{fig:trans_actions}
    Some caption text here. This is the full textwidth.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

As Werner pointed out, the above solution aligns the edges of the figures with the margins. If you also want spacing between the figures and margins as well you add `\null\hfill` on the left, and `\hfill\null` on the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove demo option in real document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \null\hfill
    \subfloat[subcaption 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image1}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[subcaption 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image2}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[subcaption 3]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image3}}
    \hfill\null
    \caption{\label{fig:trans_actions}
    Some caption text here. This is the full textwidth.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok that was too easy for you... I'll remember `\hfill` from now on.

Comment: Note that this will push the outer `\subfloat`s against the left/right margin. If you want them to be evenly spaced from the margins as well, add `\null\hfill` on the left, and `\hfill\null` on the right.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. I have updated the solution to show that as well.